# Azure Data Box Upload Files with C#

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I am trying to upload files to Azure Data Box with C# and I am running into problems.  Here is my code:

```
    private void uploadBlob()
    {
        String storageconn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StorageConnectionString");

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageconn);

        BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("democontainer");
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        String filename = guid.ToString();
        BlobClient blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(filename);
        byte[] memoryArray = new byte[3252224];
        var strm = new MemoryStream(memoryArray);
        blobClient.Upload(strm);
        strm.Close();
    }
```

When the blobClient.Upload method executes, I get the following error:

The value for one of the httpheaders is not in the correct format

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: I tested no problem occur with your code in .Net Core 2.1, Library Azure.Storage.Blobs .What your platform is?

Comment: I'm testing this is a windows form app.  .NET 4.7.2